# telegram bot api Отправка ссылки на игру. Как ботом отправить ссылку на игру

Tags: telegram

**Как отправить ссылку на игру?**

Теперь подробно.

**1)** пользователю можно отправить игру. 
**2)** Её удаётся отправить
**3)** при нажатии пользователем Play "Имя игры" то на сервер посылается запрос. И на него нужно ответить, отправив ссылку. Но нигде не написано как? В сообщении писать, что ли?

Answer (score 1):

**Отвечаю** на собственный вопрос

Нужно использовать метод **answerCallbackQuery**, читайте внимательнее документацию